# Python sockets - gethostbyname(), issue

Tags: python

I have a question regarding the socket usage in Python. I have searched and can't seem to find a solution that works for me.

I am making an IP scanner, it will scan a network using gethostbyname(), the issue is that when the name doesn't exist, it will just wait for it to time out, but I need it a lot shorter, pretty much as fast as it finds the IP's.

I have tried using the following code just as a brief idea of what I am wanting to achieve:

```
import socket
socket.setdefaulttimeout(None)
name = input("Pc: ")
try:
    host = socket.gethostbyname(name)
    print(name, host)
except BaseException:
    print("Not found")
```

This works how I would like it to, its just the amount of time it takes to tell me it was not found I need at like 0.5 seconds, not the 5-10 seconds it is currently.

If anyone can help or advise, it would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: This sounds like a problem with your DNS server, it's taking too long to return a lookup failure for some reason.

Comment: I have tried it on the network I am wanting it for, its about 10-20 seconds, but on my home network its anywhere from 3-7 seconds. I just wonder if there is a way to lower it quite dramatically

Comment: Looking up a nonexistent hostname should return a failure immediately. Unless the name is in a domain where the nameservers don't respond, then it has to wait for a timeout.

Comment: This is what I thought, but it takes its sweet time for some reason. Oh well

Comment: That's how DNS works. Messages can be lost in transit, and it uses timeouts and retransmissions. Servers can also be down, so it tries again with backup servers. It takes several iterations before it totally gives up and returns an error.

Comment: Where are you getting the names that you're trying to resolve? Most legitimate hostnames should be on nameservers that respond reliably. Can you give an example of a name that takes 10-20 seconds to report an error?